# Is it possible to give opponents full map vision?

Tags: starcraft-2

Is full map vision for opponents possible in custom maps or otherwise?

Comment: Not really sure why this is down-voted so much. It is a valid question.

Answer (score 2):

Through standard create-a-game setups, it isn't . You would have to either find a Arcade game that matches what you want or create your own using the starcraft II map editor.

Short answer: **No**
Technical answer: **Possibly, assuming you know how to use the map editor/ know somone who does.**

I also assume you want to use this like a handicap?